# Content Editor Webpart and SharePoint 2007 object model?

Tags: 2007, search, content-editor-web-part, spservices

I have to supply the query and should display the information  on the SharePoint 2007 page based on the Enterprise Search Results. I wonder, if it can be achieved through Content Editor WebPart ?

Want to display the Related info like it works in `sharepointoverflow` when we enter the title.

Answer (score 2):

In order to pull that off in a CEWP, you are going to have to use some combination of AJAX and/or [jQuery with the SharePoint Web Services](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Accessing+List+Items+using+jQuery+and+SharePoint+Web+Services).

It's a lot of work. A couple of references related to the search web service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms543175(v=office.12).aspx

http://www.mosssearch.com/searchwebservice.html

Comment: what would be the easiest way of doing it?

Comment: We'll see if others have ideas.  Far as I know this may be the only way using a CEWP.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use the CEWP and not use the CQWP instead?

Comment: I want to display the content based on the dynamic query value. Say for sample, has to display the content based on the value of selected Title . Is it possible thro’ CQWP?

Comment: How are you going to select the title? Out of the box there is little support for AJAX in SP2007 so the odds are high you will be needing a custom Web Part.